# node.js paypal https request

Tags: node.js, https, ssh, paypal

first question here, so apologies if it turns out to be something very obvious

I am trying to call the paypal adaptive payments api via node.js and am getting a 580001 invalid request error. I can make a successfull call via curl with the below message and headers, but not through node.

any help would be much appreciated.

```
    var API_endpoint = "svcs.sandbox.paypal.com";   
    var API_user = '';
    var API_pass = '';
    var API_sig = '';

    message='requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=en_US&actionType=PAY&senderEmail=test_1320882990_per@gmail.com&receiverList.receiver(0).email=test2_1320887729_biz@gmail.com& receiverList.receiver(0).amount=100.00&currencyCode=USD&cancelUrl=http://your_cancel_url&  returnUrl=http://your_return_url'

    //var params = qs.parse(message);
    //params = qs.stringify(params);

    var req_options = {
        host: API_endpoint,
        method: 'POST',
        path: '/AdaptivePayments/Pay',
        headers: {
                'Host': API_endpoint,
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                //'Content-Type': 'text/namevalue',
                'Content-Length': message.length,
                'X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT:':'NV',
                'X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT':'NV',
                'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID':API_user,
                'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD':API_pass,
                'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE':API_sig,
                'X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID':'APP-80W284485P519543T'
            }
    }

    fs.readFile('/home/dev/.ssh/sandbox-paypal-private.pem', 'ascii', function(err, key){
       fs.readFile('/home/dev/.ssh/sandbox-paypal-public.pem', 'ascii', function(err, cert){
            req_options.key=key
            req_options.cert=cert
            var req = https.request(req_options, function(res){
                console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
                console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
                res.on('data', function(d){
                    var response = d.toString();
                    console.log(response)
                });
            });
            req.write(message);
            req.end();

            req.on('error', function request_error(e) {
                console.log(e);
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it's only a copy paste problem, but your message variable does not seem to contain properly formatted string. It has white spaces and the special characters are not encoded.

```
requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=en_US&actionType=PAY&senderEmail=test_1320882990_per@gmail.com&receiverList.receiver(0).email=test2_1320887729_biz@gmail.com&receiverList.receiver(0).amount=100.00&currencyCode=USD&cancelUrl=http://your_cancel_url&  returnUrl=http://your_return_url'.
```

It should look like this:

```
requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=en_US&actionType=PAY&senderEmail=test_1320882990_per%40gmail.com&receiverList.receiver(0).email=test2_1320887729_biz%40gmail.com& receiverList.receiver(0).amount=100.00&currencyCode=USD&cancelUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fyour_cancel_url&returnUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fyour_return_url
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, and it is a copy paste problem, and the commented out functions parse and stringify take care of the special characters

Comment: Umm, but the commented out functions store encoded version to 'params' variable and not message. Also, you can not use the original message.length as content length because encoding will make it longer string.

Answer (score 1):

There's a trailing colon in one of your header fields; Rather than:

`'X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT:'`

You should have:

`'X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT'`